# Change directory of profiles that is used for Edge debugging and visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, microsoft-edge

I just learned that Edge can have different profile directories. The default one is this one and is used most of the time:

> C:\Users{userName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data

But I could create another set of profiles when I launch the msedge.exe with a **user-data-dir** parameter. For example like this:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
> --user-data-dir=C:\Blub"

If you start edge in this way, you can generate a new set of profiles that are stored in "C:\Blub".

I stumbled across this parameter when I learned how to debug with VS Code.
[This article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_attaching-to-browsers) explains that the user-data-dir parameter is also needed for this.
But here you are not using a concrete path, but a value "remote-debug-profile" like this:

> edge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
> --user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile

Also here a new "set of profiles" can be generated that will only be available when launching Edge with the remote-debug-profile parameter.

And the edge debugging only works with profiles stored there. Whenever I try to connect my visual studio code debugger for edge with a profile instance from another directory, this fails.

Is there any way how I can debug profiles that are stored in another directory?

Background is that I sync all my profiles between many devices and those tools prevent me from storing profiles at the default place for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setting the `--remote-debugging-port` debug connection, need to set a separate --user-data-dir forces a new instance of the browser to be opened. If this flag isn't given, then the command will open a new window of any running browser and not enter debug mode.

1. Go to `edge://version` in Microsoft Edge and view the property **Command-line**.
2. If this flag isn't given you need to close all edge processes. Please run the `taskkill /f /im msedge.exe` in Command-line.
   [image]

Note: When setting a separate remote-debug-profile file path, please note that the profile path is enclosed in quotation marks.

**Update：**
Also, we can manage to get debugging with other profile path.
（For example: I created the path **C:/debugging** and my **cmd** is `start msedge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222  --user-data-dir="C:\debugging" --profile-directory="Profile 1"`）
Go to `edge://version` in Microsoft Edge and view the property **Command-line**. It shows below screenshot：
[image]
In the same way, you can specify other paths for debugging.
However, you need to make sure all Edge processes are closed, and check if the separate path is correct.

Comment: Not sure if I made myself clear enough. I am talking in my question about the directory where the browser profiles are stored, not about the directory of my web projects. I think that the cwd contains the files of my project, not of the edge browser profiles.

Comment: In your description: "I try to connect my visual studio code debugger for edge with a profile instance from another directory, this fails. "
Is there any error message?

Comment: Yes - it tries to connect for a long time. After a while it failes with a "cannot connect to instance with port 9222" or something. If I choose a different profile directory it works instanntly.

Comment: Hi, I had updated my answer, please help check and if you have any question, please let us know.

Comment: Could you really manage to get debugging to work with another profile path (for example: C:/debugging? For me this does only work for the default dir in Program files

Comment: I had updated my answer, please help check. Thanks, Regards